# AEBS crashing after iOS 8

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, ios, airport, appletv

Okay, let me start with the caveat that I'm a bit in the dark about what exactly is going on here. I'll try to provide all the necessary info but feel free to ask for more if I leave something out.

The problem I am having is with my wifi network periodically "crashing" (5th Gen AEBS (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirPort#AirPort_Extreme_Base_Station) and 2nd gen Express). By crashing I mean the network briefly loses internet connection and disappears (dropping all devices), then returns, usually more quickly than if I had performed a manual restart.

As for what is causing this, I first noticed it while streaming radio directly via AppleTV (3rd gen). The problem started with the latest software update (7) for the ATV, which was right around the time of the iOS 8 release. Initially I found this thread: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6546699 and figured the problem was a bug in the ATV software update. However, I have now noticed some other things causing the same behavior, such as trying to stream audio (also radio--this time from an app) on an iPad Air. Streaming of other types and particularly any sort of "high bandwidth" activity in general seem to also create the same sort of network crash, though not as reliably. The ATV/radio stream issue is reproducible without fail--every 5 -10 minutes it goes down. Streaming radio from any OS X machine via AirPlay works without error.

These are all new problems that never occurred before the recent software updates, but I'm unsure if it is an issue with iOS, ATV, the AEBS, or some configuration of one or more of these devices. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You need to explain what AEBS stands for if your going to use an acronym like that.

Comment: Sorry about that: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirPort#AirPort_Extreme_Base_Station

Comment: What firmware on the base stations (please don't say, "the latest", look up the actual version number and report it)?

Comment: Also, what does the status indicator light on the front of the base station do when this happens?

Comment: @Spiff It's been several months since I posted this question, and the issue seems to have resolved with one of the AppleTV updates that have been pushed since then, though I'm not sure which as I have been out of town intermittently. Also, I'm not sure if you were referring to the where I used "the latest" above, but I had included the actual version number (7). The base stations are currently on 7.6.4 but I don't recall what they were on at the time. They are set to check for firmware weekly though, and so were likely on whatever was current at the time.